# Change list to list of associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I have list of unique elements and want to change it to list of associative arrays. What is the most elegant way to do this? I tried foreach but it looks bogus.

**Expected Input:**

```
array('2019-10-01', '2019-10-02', '2019-10-03')
```

**Expected Output:**

```
array(array('day' => '2019-10-01'), array('day' => '2019-10-02'), array('day' => '2019-10-03'))
```

Comment: You can do this something like this array( 'day' => array('2019-10-01', '2019-10-02', '2019-10-03')) but the way you've shown can't do.

Comment: The keys has to be unique.

Comment: _“I tried foreach but it looks bogus”_ - your stated _requirement_ is “bogus”, as in impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$array = array('2019-10-01', '2019-10-02', '2019-10-03');
$output = array_map(function ($v) { return array('day' => $v); }, $array);
```

or a simple `foreach`:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $output[] = array('day' => $v);
}
```

In both cases the output is the same:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2019-10-01
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2019-10-02
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2019-10-03
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MMlbf)

Comment: array_map looks like the most elegant solution! Just wondering if it is faster than foreach? Thanks!

Comment: @dtar generally you will find that a simple `foreach` is faster (for example, there isn't the overhead of a function call). The benefit of PHP's `array_*` functions is usually just in terms of making cleaner (more elegant) code.

Answer (score 0):

See this short code example. it iterates over the given `array` and associates a `key` with an increment:

```
$a = Array('2019-10-01', '2019-10-02', '2019-10-03');

$b = [];

for($x = 0; $x < count($a); $x++) {
  $b['day' . $x] = $a[$x];
}

print_r($b);
// output: Array ( [day0] => 2019-10-01 [day1] => 2019-10-02 [day2] => 2019-10-03 )
```